# С++ Правильный вызов унаследованной реализации

Tags: c++, ооп

Всех приветствую.
Пытаюсь работать с С++ и возникла задачка. Требуется вызвать определенную реализацию функции-члена дочернего объекта класса `Parent` в зависимости от значения определенной строки.

Имеем родительский класс:

```
class Parent {
public:
  virtual int do();
}
```

Дочерние:

```
class Child1 : public Parent {
public:
  int do();
}

class Child2 : public Parent {
public:
  int do();
}
```

Нам нужно в зависимости от `std::string task` вызвать ту либо иную реализацию функции-члена `do()`. При этом дочерние классы будут в дальнейшем добавляться, функции-члены тоже. Желательно на каждом вызове той либо иной реализации не городить огороды условий.

Спасибо!

Comment: Напишите фабрику, которая будет отдавать вам нужного чайлда `std::unique_ptr<Parent> getHandler(std::string task);`. Там и разбейте огород условий, который будет скрыт от клиентского кода благодаря полиморфизму

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно сделать [Фабричный метод](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)):

```
Parent* createChild(const std::string &data){
    if(data == "Child1"){
        retrun new Child1;
    }

    if(data == "Child2"){
        retrun new Child2;
    }

    retrun nullptr;
}
```

Использовать так:

```
std::unique_ptr<Parent> parent(createChild(data));
parent->do(); //какой именно do зависит от data
```

---

На этом можно бы и остановиться, но лично я люблю в таких случаях использовать идиому [конверт-письмо](https://habrahabr.ru/post/64369/):

```
class Child : public Parent{
    std::unique_ptr<Parent> _parent;
public:
    explicit Child(const std::string &data):
       _parent(createChild(data))
    {}
    int do(){
        return _parent->do();
    }
    Parent* createChild(const std::string &data) const;
};
```

Класс `Child` инкапсулирует процесс создания конкретных экземпляров и делегирует свои обязанности созданному объекту. Пользоваться так:

```
Child child(data);
child.do(); //какой именно do зависит от data
```